# How to create a JPAQL to pull a tree of parent with multiple children collections and avoid Hibernate Illegal attempt to dereference collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to mimic a eager fetch for a specific situation only.I use `spring-data-jpa` with `hibernate 4.1` as implementation. i have `User`, `Role` and `Right`. `Role` and `User` have many-to-many with additional field thus mapped as an Entity `RoleUser`. `Role` and `Right` also are in `many-to-many` mapped as an Entity `RoleRight`.

I would like to load all right and role for a user into the `Authorization` mechanism of the application when needed. this query below is giving `illegal attempt to dereference collection`

```
   List<Role> roles = (List<Role>)em.createQuery("select r from RoleImpl r JOIN FETCH r.roleRightMap rrm JOIN FETCH rrm.right ur WHERE r.userRoleMap.user.ID=:id ")
            .setParameter("id", ID).getResultList();
```

How can it be rewritten to load the role and its mapping thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Never mind. it was an oversight.

The query should have been like this :

```
select r from RoleImpl r LEFT JOIN FETCH r.roleRightMap rrm LEFT JOIN FETCH r.userRoleMap urm WHERE urm.user.ID=:id
```